# How does G729 Codec compress down to 8kbps?

Tags: audio, codec, telephony, pcm

As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.729:

- It has a sample frequency of 8kHz, so every second it takes 8000 Samples:

> Sampling frequency 8 kHz/16-bit (80 samples for 10 ms frames)

- It has a fixed frame size of 80 bits for 10ms frame => 8 bit each ms / each sample

> Fixed frame size (10 bytes (80 bits) for 10 ms frame)

Yet its only running at 8kbps

> Fixed bit rate (8 kbit/s 10 ms frames)

Maybe my English is failing me here, but how is it possible that 8000 samples a second, with 8 bit used in each sample, end up not at 8000*8 = 64000 bit/s = 64kbps, but at 8kbps?
I must be missing something here, i know G729 heavily compresses audio, but i do not understand at what step it does this.

I can only assume that it somehow has an "input" of 8000 samples a second, but it somehow "averages" those samples together every 8 samples, resulting in only 1000 samples a second? Or does it just skip 7 out of 8 samples? If so, why even take 8000 samples a second, instead of just directly taking 1000? How exactly does this step of "compression" work?

Comment: That’s exactly how I read “80 samples for 10 ms frames”. 80 samples go into one frame. Cannot research further atm, sorry.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the "...using code-excited linear prediction speech coding (CS-ACELP)" part?

Comment: My arithmetic says : 80 bits for 10 ms frame, so 100 frames per second, gives 80*100=8000 which is exactly 8kbps.

Comment: @harrymc Right, thats the thing that i dont understand: The article says 80 bit per 10ms. But it also says 80 Samples per 10ms, and a Sample has a size of 8bit. Now i want to know, how does it get to only the 80 bit per 10ms? I assume it does some grouping of multiple sampling, it is cool to know the name of the algorithm that does the compression, but i want to know at what point exactly it compresses. Does it compress the samples? or a group of samples? or the final voice payload?

Answer (score 1):

Your article treats the compression as if its length is guaranteed,
which I find exceedingly strange. I don't think that any compression
algorithm can guarantee the length of the compressed data
(except if data can be dropped).

The article
[VoIP Codecs + Bandwidth = Your Call Quality](https://getvoip.com/blog/2013/05/31/voip-codecs-bandwidth-your-call-quality/)
has indeed this text:

> G.729 compresses 64Kbps into only 8Kbs, a compression ratio of 8 to 1, but **in practice** you get bandwidth savings of about 3 or 4 to 1. G.729 codecs use about 24-30Kbps.

This indeed seems to indicate that too-long compressed data is constrained
to fit into the allowed size margins.

If you wish to learn about the algorithm used, you will find some
information in the article
[G.729 FAMILY OF LOW-BIT-RATE Codecs (VoIP)](http://what-when-how.com/voip/g-729-family-of-low-bit-rate-codecs-voip/).

I won't copy here the technical explanation, as it contains too much
terminology that I don't understand.

I replicate here only the schema for the encoder
(this part at least I can grok):

[image]

Comment: Constant bitrate is a staple of lossy audio and video compression. It's important for broadcasting.